# PySFTP put not always puts files, is it a coding problem?

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

So recently I wrote a code that put files from one folder to an SFTP folder. It works generally, but many times it fails to upload the data, and I have no clue way. Do you have any tips?

```
import os
import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None 

#Set these to make the code run
shared_aim_fd='' #the folder where you copy from
sftp_user=''
sftp_pw=''
sftp_site=''
sftp_folder_name='' #where you want to copy to

for od_files in os.listdir(shared_aim_fd):
    myUsername =str(sftp_user) 
    myPassword =str(sftp_pw)
    myHostname=str(sftp_site)
    mySFTPFolderName=str(sftp_folder_name)

    try:
        with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
            print ("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
            #Make sure we have the folder where we want to push it
            if not sftp.isdir(mySFTPFolderName): 
                #if not, then create one 
                sftp.makedirs(mySFTPFolderName)
            sftp.put(shared_aim_fd+od_files,str(mySFTPFolderName+'/'+od_files))
            sftp.close()

    except:
        print("Upload failed")
        pass
```

Comment: first tip: always use `expect Exception as ex: print(ex)` to see error message - it helps to resolve problems

Comment: Or get rid of the `try` block altogether and see what kind of exception you're getting and _what line_ is causing it

Comment: second tip: use `print()` to see values in variable in different places - it helps to find problem. Later you can remove `print()`.

Comment: user name, password, side and folder name are strings and you don't need `str()`. Maybe you forgot to add `/` in `shared_aim_fd+od_files` ? Using `print(shared_aim_fd+od_files)` you could confirm it. You could even use `os.path.join(folder, filename)` to create path. To upload every file you connect again and again - maybe you should connect only once and later use `for od_files` to uploads files. But don't close connection after every connection. Frankly, `with ... as sftp:` should close it automatically without `close()`

Comment: @furas this is a part of a bigger code, str() is there to make it sure that I am not trying to push integer data (pw, username etc.).
So the code is working in like 80% and does the pushes, but there is 20% when it fails

Comment: @furas I'll use the Exception!, can it be that the try fails on the sftp.close(), and until then the sftp.put could not finish the upload?

Comment: print exception and you will see what is the problem. For me  problems can be rather `shared_aim_fd+od_files`. If `shared_aim_fd` doesn't have `/` at the end then you create wrong path and it can't read local file to send it. I would use `print(shared_aim_fd)` to see path.